# Postgres shell logout weirdness on debian

Tags: linux, debian

So, strangest thing happening on Debian PostgreSQL user:

```
lab3:~# su - postgres
postgres@lab3:~$ plogout
lab3:~#
```

And:

```
lab3:~# su postgres
postgres@lab3:/root$ pexit
lab3:~#
```

What is happening here? Well, if right after I use `su` to change to the `postgres` user, using `su -` or `su`, I press `p` (like I was going to write `psql`) I get logged out by `logout` or `exit`. That doesn't happen if I press enter and then press `p` on the line below, it only happens if the first thing I press is `p`. Apparently it happens with any character, but sometimes it fails on `e` or `a`.

Are you asking *WHAAAAAT?* Yeah. Me too. This is happening on all our Debian Lenny machines but not on at least one Squeeze we have.

Comment: What does `/etc/passwd` detail for postgres' shell?

Comment: @jscott /bin/bash

Comment: Guess, and therefore not answer-worthy, but: some crazy scriptage in .bashrc/.bash_profile, maybe? The scenario you describe is beyond bizarre.

Comment: Incidentally, can you log in from console or ssh to the postgres user with different results?

Comment: `su - postgres` set all parameters, as when user postgres login to the machine (including .bash files for the opening relation), but `su postgres` don't do this. It can deal with this behavior...